# Binding update problem

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding

I have a problem with binding update when binding property is changed.
Look at the code below. I will explain my issue in the following example.

```
public class SettingsControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        string _value = "test";

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public SettingsControl() { }


     public string Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; OnPropertyChanged("Value"); }
        }
    }

<local:SettingsControl x:Key="Settings"></local:SettingsControl>

<TextBox Height="72" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource Settings} }"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Settings} }" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" />
<Button Height="100" Click="button1_Click" />
```

and code behind:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SettingsControl settings = new SettingsControl();
        settings.Value = "new value";
    }
```

Now, when I change text in `TextBox` everything works just fine. New text is shown in `TextBlock`.
But if I set new text in code to the `settings.Value` nothing happens.

What I suppose to do in order to change `settings.Value` in code and affect `TextProperty` in `TextBlock`.

EDIT: Solution below for those who had the same problem as me:

```
    SettingsControl settings = (SettingsControl)this.Resources["Settings"];
    settings.Value = "new value";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code behind, you're setting the value on a *new instance*, not on the instance being used.

Try changing the code behind to:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set the Value on "this"
    this.Value = "new value";
}
```

That being said, properties on a "Control" are typically handled via making a Dependency  Property, not via `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  This allows them to be set and used correctly in XAML, and participate fully in binding in more scenarios.

Comment: But I cannot reach `Value` via `this.Value`. I get error "'binding.MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'Value'...". Thank you for suggestion, I'll look closer to Dependency Property.

Comment: @Maku: In that case, you need to get the proper reference to the control - not create a new instance, but rather use "this.mySettingsControl.Value"

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make Mode=TwoWay ;-)

Comment: In this particular example of course we can do that (Mode=TwoWay and in code TextBlock.Text = "new value"). I was looking for general solution. Thanks to Reed Copsey problem is solved.